# Human caravan ignoring accessible Trade Depot

Tags: dwarf-fortress

A human caravan just has entered and leaved my map, without even trying to get to my Trade Depot. No special announcements are issued at that time. I've checked Depot accessibility, and as you can see from the screenshot, it's perfectly accessible.

[Here is my save file (for DF v0.34.03)](http://dffd.bay12games.com/file.php?id=12861)

[image]

Have I done anything wrong? I don't want to lose the dwarven caravan arriving this autumn like this. There are so many crafts to be sold!

Comment: Is the path towards the depot 3 spaces wide at all places?

Comment: @antipattern Yes I can confirm it is. The green text `Depot accessible` also implies that. Please download my save file and check it yourself.

Comment: The "accessible" only means that there is one path from one(!) map edge to the depot. I have read in `boatmurdered` that it is possible for the caravan to spawn at another edge from which there is no such path. Make sure none of the map edges is blocked off, for example, by a river or canyon.

Comment: @antipattern Oh there is a river to the right to my fort! Going to build a bridge over it... However, I remember _this_ human caravan came from the top edge, and I didn't find anything blocking their path :(

Comment: The Caravan always consists of Diplomats as well as the actual wagons. Not 100% sure about it, but I think the diplomats may spawn independently of the wagon. I can only recommend reading the happenings at boatmurdered, it is equally entertaining as it is informative towards quirks and tricks in the game.

Comment: @antipattern I just found in the unit screen that [a wagon is deceased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjQGt.png). Is this relevant?

Comment: I'd guess so. Most likely there was something scaring the wagon so it could not reach the Depot. Any known/unknown foes on your map perhaps?

Comment: @antipattern At the very least, there were no known foes on the map. Fortunately, the dwarven caravan made it to my Trade Depot in the autumn, so I think there are no problems now. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Weird. I shall put these insights into an answer. Sad not to be able to help you though.

Comment: @antipattern Your answer would definitely help others with the same problem, accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, consider the following things:

Is the path towards the depot 3 spaces wide at all places`? If not, there is no way for the wagons the reach your outpost. The diplomats will, however.

Make sure *all* parts of the map are marked accesible. Because if a wagon spawns weird, it will try to path to your depot, even if it is not possible.

Temporary obstacles will count, maybe some enemies are scraring the wagon.

If not of these helps, you  messed up your fort.